# ASP.NET MVC 5 SignalR, SqlDependency and EntityFramework 6 - the sqlparameter is already contained by another sqlparametercollection

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, signalr, sqldependency

I am beginner with SignalR and SQLDepedency. I am trying to implement SignalR  using EF Code First Approach. I am getting the error **The sqlparameter is already contained by another sqlparametercollection** if I am using where condition in LINQ class.

```
public class MessageHub : Hub
{
    internal NotifierEntity NotifierEntity { get; private set; }
    private MyDbContext db = new MyDbContext();
    public void DispatchToClient()
    {
        Clients.All.broadcastMessage("Refresh");
    }


    public void Initialize(String userName)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userName))
        {
            NotifierEntity = db.GetNotifierEntity<Messages>(db.Messages.Where(x=>x.ApplicationUser.UserName== userName && !x.Status));
            if (NotifierEntity == null)
                return;
            Action<String> dispatcher = (t) => { DispatchToClient(); };
            PushSqlDependency.Instance(NotifierEntity, dispatcher);
        }
    }

}
```

The NotifierEntity Class

```
public class NotifierEntity
{
    ICollection<SqlParameter> sqlParameters = new List<SqlParameter>();

    public String SqlQuery { get; set; }

    public String SqlConnectionString { get; set; }

    public ICollection<SqlParameter> SqlParameters
    {
        get
        {
            return sqlParameters;
        }
        set
        {
            sqlParameters = value;
        }
    }

    public static NotifierEntity FromJson(String value)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("NotifierEntity Value can not be null!");
        return new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<NotifierEntity>(value);
    }
}

public static class NotifierEntityExtentions
{
    public static String ToJson(this NotifierEntity entity)
    {
        if (entity == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("NotifierEntity can not be null!");
        return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(entity);
    }
}

public class PushSqlDependency
{
    static PushSqlDependency instance = null;
    readonly SqlDependencyRegister sqlDependencyNotifier;
    readonly Action<String> dispatcher;

    public static PushSqlDependency Instance(NotifierEntity notifierEntity, Action<String> dispatcher)
    {
        if (instance == null)
            instance = new PushSqlDependency(notifierEntity, dispatcher);
        return instance;
    }

    private PushSqlDependency(NotifierEntity notifierEntity, Action<String> dispatcher)
    {
        this.dispatcher = dispatcher;
        sqlDependencyNotifier = new SqlDependencyRegister(notifierEntity);
        sqlDependencyNotifier.SqlNotification += OnSqlNotification;
    }

    internal void OnSqlNotification(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
    {
        dispatcher("Refresh123");
    }
}

public class SqlDependencyRegister
{
    public event SqlNotificationEventHandler SqlNotification;

    readonly NotifierEntity notificationEntity;

    internal SqlDependencyRegister(NotifierEntity notificationEntity)
    {
        this.notificationEntity = notificationEntity;
        RegisterForNotifications();
    }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Security",
    "CA2100:Review SQL queries for security vulnerabilities")]
    void RegisterForNotifications()
    {
        using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(notificationEntity.SqlConnectionString))
        using (var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(notificationEntity.SqlQuery, sqlConnection))
        {
            foreach (var sqlParameter in notificationEntity.SqlParameters)
            {
                sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(sqlParameter);
            }

            sqlCommand.Notification = null;
            var sqlDependency = new SqlDependency(sqlCommand);
            sqlDependency.OnChange += OnSqlDependencyChange;
            if (sqlConnection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                sqlConnection.Open();
            sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }

    void OnSqlDependencyChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
    {
        if (SqlNotification != null)
            SqlNotification(sender, e);
        RegisterForNotifications();
    }
}

public delegate void SqlNotificationEventHandler(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e);
```

If I am using the same query without any parameters, the code is working perfectly. I can see the database changes instantly in frontend. The issue is coming after added a parameter in Where clause.

I got this idea from below link
https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1075852/ASP-NET-MVC-SignalR-SqlDependency-and-EntityFramew

Sourcecode link

we.tl/njwwLl8g36

Comment: Have you tried adding new parameters based on the old parameters data instead of trying to add the notifiers parameters in the `sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(sqlParameter);` as per the error message?

Comment: Could you please download and take a look the code from the link I have added in my question. Please give your suggestions for this kind of implementation   (we.tl/njwwLl8g36)